# Sound problems with non-KDE applications on Kubuntu

Tags: 10.04, sound, kubuntu, kde

I m a newbie to Linux and have installed Kubuntu 10.04 LTS.
There are problems regarding the web browsers (google-chrome and mozilla) and also in vlc player...no sound could be heard.
But the dragon player works well.

What could be the problem and possible solutions for it?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly one of the non-KDE things you're using pulled in Pulseaudio.  If that's the case, Pulse needs to be at the *top* of the list in the multimedia settings in System Settings in order for things to work correctly.

Comment: That is what I do.

Comment: @mico : thanks for the reply but still its not working.....

Answer (score 0):

KDE uses a different sound engine than GNOME. It uses Phonon. I would start there. Go to Settings, System settings, Multimedia in the Hardware section and Phonon at the bottom. Click on backend.

Try switching from Gstreamer to Xine. Sometimes Gstreamer and PulseAudio do not work well with some sound cards and Xine gives better results. Many GNOME users get better results by installing Totem-xine than using the default Totem with Gstreamer. It is easy to switch back if you don't like it. You may have to logout and back in for that setting to take effect.

If it is already Xine then you can try Gstreamer in the same way.